# Jasper Reports case-sensitive font names

Tags: fonts, jasper-reports

I have a number of reports that show text fields with HTML markup. Some HTML elements have style and font-family assigned to them. The font-family is not case-sensitive when you render the HTML in a browser, so the following options give the exact same results in a browser:

1. style="font-family:verdana;"
2. style="font-family:Verdana;"

Please note the only difference between the two options is lowercase "v" versus uppercase in font-family.

When I export a report to PDF Jasper Reports can find and use the font just fine if the first letter of the font-family is capital, but it fails to find the font if it's all in lowercase.
I don't have control over the HTML text as it gets generated somewhere else. Searching and replacing the font names in the HTML is not a good option as it can be time consuming and needs to be done for a lot of reports and various font names.
Does anybody know a solution to force Jasper Reports ignore the case when searching for a font name?
Your help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I added multiple mappings in the fonts.xml. Not sure if this is the best solution, but it at least would generate the PDF without blowing up over fonts.

```
<fontFamily name="Verdana">
    <normal><![CDATA[fonts/VERDANA.TTF]]></normal>
    <bold><![CDATA[fonts/VERDANAB.TTF]]></bold>
    <italic><![CDATA[fonts/VERDANAI.TTF]]></italic>
    <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/VERDANAZ.TTF]]></boldItalic>
    <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
</fontFamily>
<fontFamily name="verdana">
    <normal><![CDATA[fonts/VERDANA.TTF]]></normal>
    <bold><![CDATA[fonts/VERDANAB.TTF]]></bold>
    <italic><![CDATA[fonts/VERDANAI.TTF]]></italic>
    <boldItalic><![CDATA[fonts/VERDANAZ.TTF]]></boldItalic>
    <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
</fontFamily>
```